# Excel VBA Using Sum in a For Next Loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have a for next loop where I have dimmed the row number as "i". I would like to sum up the following range - within row "i", from column C to M in a For Next Loop. I have the following codes:

```
Range("N" & i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("C" & i & ":" & "M" & i))
```

I have also tried the following:

```
Range("N" & i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("C" & i), Range("M" & i))
Range("N" & i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum("C" & i & ":" & "M" & i)
```

I guess my main problem is I cannot figure out the correct way to reference the dynamic row number i in the code, hence the error. Would appreciate your help.

Comment: Your top version is fine though I would ensure you use the Worksheet reference and not use an implicit Activesheet reference. How are you using this in a loop?

Comment: `Rows(i).Range("C1:M1")` would also work (but add the worksheet qualifier as recommended by QHarr)

Comment: @QHarr Thanks QHarr, my top version didn't work somehow. I had a problem when referencing the worksheets, because both my workbook and worksheets' names change constantly, so I used the implicit Activesheet reference, but you're right - if I reference using worksheet index number ```Worksheets(7).Range("N" & i).Value - Worksheets(2).Range("N" & i).Value```, the result is equivalent to ```0- Worksheets(2).Range("N" & i).Value```. I think there's something fundamental I'm missing here so the referencing are so out of line

Comment: The index refers only to the position of the sheet in the workbook. Perhaps you could use the sheet codenames which cannot be changed except from the VB editor (or code).